# The executing order of capture and bubble for two same listeners in js

Tags: javascript, html, events, capture

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>capture and bubble</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  #child{
    background: red;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
  }
  #father{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:green;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='father'>
      <div id='child'></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var parent = document.getElementById("father");
  var child = document.getElementById('child');
  var html = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
  var body = document.body;
  parent.addEventListener("click",function() {
    console.log("I am capturing parent");
  },true);
   parent.addEventListener("click",function() {
    console.log("I am parent");
  },false);
   child.addEventListener("click",function() {
    console.log("I am capturing child");
  },true);
  child.addEventListener("click",function() {
    console.log("I am child");
  },false);
  body.addEventListener("click",function() {
    console.log("I am capturing body");
  },true);  
  body.addEventListener("click",function() {
    console.log("I am body");
  },false);
  html.addEventListener("click",function() {
    console.log("I am capturing html");
  },true);
  html.addEventListener("click",function() {
    console.log("I am html");
  },false);
  parent.addEventListener("click",function() {
    console.log("I am capturing parent");
  },true);
   parent.addEventListener("click",function() {
    console.log("I am parent");
  },false);
</script>
</html>
```

For the above  html containning a js to display executing order of capture and  bubble,i have binded two listeners of capture and bubble two times for the parent(div father),one pair of capture and bubble for the parent(div father) is from 5th line till 10th line in the js script part; other pair of capture and bubble for the parent(div father) is at the ending of the js script part.

Click the green div(father div),get the result in console.

```
test.html:50 I am capturing html
test.html:44 I am capturing body
test.html:32 I am capturing parent
test.html:35 I am parent
test.html:56 I am capturing parent
test.html:59 I am parent
test.html:47 I am body
test.html:53 I am html
```

Why the result is not the following?

```
test.html:50 I am capturing html
test.html:44 I am capturing body
test.html:32 I am capturing parent
test.html:56 I am capturing parent
test.html:35 I am parent
test.html:59 I am parent
test.html:47 I am body
test.html:53 I am html
```

Please explain it in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MDN documentation for `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) states:

> **Note**: For event listeners attached to the event target, the event is in the target phase, rather than the capturing and bubbling phases. Events in the target phase will trigger all listeners on an element in the order they were registered, regardless of the `useCapture` parameter.

This is what happens here. The event listeners are attached to the event target (`parent` in your example), therefore the event is in the target phase and the listeners are triggered in the order they were registered.

Note that if you click `child`, this doesn't happen because the event is in capture or bubbling phase. The result as expected is:

```
I am capturing html
I am capturing body
I am capturing parent
I am capturing parent
I am capturing child
I am child
I am parent
I am parent
I am body
I am html
```

There is a good explanation and diagram of the event flow [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most importing thing is that target phase trigger both capturing and bubbling action.

[other material with very understandable language states here](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)

the 2nd phase (“target phase”: the event reached the element) is not handled separately: 
handlers on both capturing and bubbling phases trigger at that phase.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed that MDN updated the states for addEventListener:

> Note: For event listeners attached to the event target, the event is in the target phase, rather than the capturing and bubbling phases. Event listeners in the capturing phase are called before event listeners in any non-capturing phases.

that means the result exactly same as your expected

```
I am capturing html
I am capturing body
I am capturing parent
I am capturing parent
I am capturing child
I am child
I am parent
I am parent
I am body
I am html
```

[console in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQtJr.png)